# customize server in GPS Tracker

Tags: gps

Is there any GPS tracker available in which I can set server's location (some IP) to which that device will send notifications (GPS data).

I want to create my own GPS receiver server.

Comment: Are you trying to log GPS data on some mobile device then upload that data via a wireless communications link like Bluetooth or WiFi when the device is within range of a server?

Comment: I think you'll find a number of modems with integrated GPS that can be configured this way from Sierra Wireless, Enfora, and others... I think you'll find a better approach a server that polls the modem though... I worked for a company with patents in this area...so beware.

Comment: I don't think there is enough info for a complete answer, what are you looking for? are you looking  to make your own tracker or do you want an out of the box solution? Your question is still very vague.

Comment: I'm also searching for a device like this, did you fine one?

Comment: I have just bought a PST-T100 "GO Everywhere" GPS Tracker. I'm able to set the IP and port on the device with SMS commands. All i need now is the server software, but i'm "working" on that issue overe here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633467/gps-tracker-sends-data-to-ip-whats-next

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, but I think what you're asking is:  Is there a way to track entities that send out location information by having them send their data to a server?

Essentially, you need some method of:

A) Figuring out where on earth you are (you use a GPS receiver for that)

B) Way to send that information to like a server somewhere.

C) A server that handles and manages that information.

[APRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Packet_Reporting_System), an amateur radio service, supports doing this.  For example, from reporting stations, you can plot their [locations on a map](http://aprs.fi).

Comment: *Holy freaking cool!* **+∞**

Comment: Remember that you have to have a HAM radio license to use APRS.  It should be pretty obvious, but just making sure.

Comment: can you please name some GPS tracker device in which I can customize server?

Answer (score 1):

I would personally setup a LAMP server, make a simple API out of your choice of language, I would use PHP. When you want to send data you would send a POST or GET request to your server with your data and the SQL Database would store it, from there you can do what ever you want with the data, like adding a googlemaps.

another idea would be to send it over ssh and store it in a file.

My question to you is, how are you sending the data to the server? ( TCP, Serial, smoke signals)

Comment: LAMP = Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP